# PHP echo to another page

Tags: php

What i wrong with this code below. I am trying to get it to echo to another page but it does not seem to pick up the data that is on the database.

```
<?php
{
    // connect to server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "u", "") or die(mysql_error());
    //select database
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

    //Create a query that selects all data from the PATIENT table where the username and password match
    $query = "SELECT`Appointment_id`, `Doctor_id`, `Patient_id`, `Appointment_time`, `Appointment_date` FROM `Appointment`";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_id'] = $row['Appointment_id'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id'];

    }
}
?>
```

Appointment.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d"  data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content">

<?php
{
    // connect to server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
    //select database
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $query = "SELECT `Appointment_id`, `Doctor_id`, `Patient_id`, `Appointment_time`, `Appointment_date` FROM `Appointment`";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_id'] = $row['Appointment_id'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id'];

    }
}
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Echo onto this page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Details
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
              <form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
            <strong>Your Details</strong>
            <br />
            <br />
            Appointment: <?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_id'];?>
            <br />
            <br />
            Doctor: <?php echo $_SESSION['Doctor_id'];?>
            <br />
            <br />



             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The second section is where the database is picking up the information (Appointment) and the third shows where i need it to display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=details1.php">
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Login Process
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
```

login.php

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=details1.php">
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Login Process
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">

<?php
// takes the variables from action script and assigns them php variables names
$user = $_POST ['username'];
$pass = $_POST ['password'];

// if there is a user name and password
if ($user && $pass)
{
    // connect to server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
    //select database
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

    //Create a query that selects all data from the PATIENT table where the username and password match
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE Username = '$user' AND Password = '$pass'";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1)
    {
        //sends back a data of "Success"
        echo "Successful Login";
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Title'] = $row['Title'];
        $_SESSION['First_name'] = $row['First_name'];
        $_SESSION['Last_name'] = $row['Last_name'];
        $_SESSION['Address'] = $row['Address'];
        $_SESSION['Line_2'] = $row['Line_2'];
        $_SESSION['Line_3'] = $row['Line_3'];
        $_SESSION['Postcode'] = $row['Postcode'];
        $_SESSION['Home'] = $row['Home'];
        $_SESSION['Mobile'] = $row['Mobile'];



    }
    else
    {
        //sends back a message of "failed"
        echo "Unsuccessful Login";
    }
}

?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wheres the rest of the code?

Comment: where is session_start();

Comment: what do you want to ask

Comment: Need to know if this code is correct because when i echo it on another page, it does not show the info.

Comment: please add complete code, we can not do hit and try here, we asked session is not there and you said it is there. One of us said there is no where clause and you said it is there :) please give full details so we all can help you

Comment: Still using mysql_* library we see for new code - bit old skool

Answer (score 0):

Please use `session_start()` on both of the pages, if you dont start that you will not be able to use that

**EDIT**

Create a test page to see your sessions are working?

if yes then test that on other page

also try adding a simple echo in your if condition where you are setting the session values. If that echo triggers it means your code is correct and something is wrong with SESSION. And if echo dont trigger, it means your code is not correct and sessions are not being set

Answer (score 0):

please add at the top

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Ok so here I believe the logical error lies

```
$query = "SELECT `Appointment_id`, `Doctor_id`, `Patient_id`, `Appointment_time`, `Appointment_date` FROM `Appointment`";

$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
if ($num == 1)
{

}
```

Since your query has no `WHERE` clause, it is returning all records that there are, and You are setting the SESSION values only when there is 1 record. You should also have an `else` condition to see what happens in real.

`Create a query that selects all data from the PATIENT table where the username and password match`

But your query does not do that, it gets data for all the `PATIENT`s

For example if your username and password came from a `POST`ed form then you could do

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
```

Then you could use both those values inside a `WHERE` clause. Since I do not know the structure of your tables apart from just reading your query, I can not write it exactly.  But just to give you an idea, a where could be like

```
$query="SELECT id from YourTable where $username='$username' and password='$password'"
```

**Very important to note since you are a beginner** : `mysql_*` functions should no longer be used. If you are starting, don't start with something that's gone. Read about `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

**Edit 2:**

Ok great, so do this

1. On successful login where you store Patient's details in SESSION, also store `Patient_id` like `$_SESSION['Patient_id'] = $row['Patient_id'];` //or maybe its just `id`. Check your table
2. On Appointment.php change your query to

   $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]);
   $query = "SELECT `Appointment_id`, `Doctor_id`, `Patient_id`, `Appointment_time`, `Appointment_date` FROM `Appointment` where Patient_id=$pid";
3. Add an else condition below your `if($num==1) { }` block like

PHP

```
else{
echo "Somehow we didn't get 1 record";
die();
}
```

Comment: Yeah i took the username of to post it on here

Comment: @user2216325 Also note that if this is same in real query then its invalid syntax `SELECT`Appointment_id`. You need to have a space after SELECT

Comment: Sorry i am new to php. So i need to add a WHERE clause and else condition. Any chance you could help with that?

Comment: 1. Where is your `PATIENT` table. 2. Where do you `LOGIN`

Comment: Login is on another php page, once the user logs in, it displays there details. From there it goes to another page where they can make appointments which is the code shown above. I need it to display appointment availability details.

Comment: Ok then do you have Patient ID stored in session after login?

Comment: I have posted my login.php code. This works fine and it displays the details on another page

Comment: I now need it to get appointment information (regarding the selected patient) from the database and display appointments availability to them. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: The server database is all linked up together

Comment: You see the successful login page is the login.php page. So the user logs in at login.html and then the php shows if it was successful. If i add $_SESSION['Patient_id'] = $row['Patient_id']; then this will also display when i am echoing the patient details on the details page before the appointments are displayed  if that makes sense.

Comment: On the details page, i just need it to echo patient details without showing the id

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `$_SESSION` .. you need to use session_start() immediately after php opening tag

```
<?php
  session_start();
```

and not only on this page .. session_start() should be there on every page where you want you use `session_start()` .. otherwise `$_SESSION` is not accessible..

Answer (score 0):

if your just trying to get the first row

```
$query = "SELECT `Appointment_id`, `Doctor_id`, `Patient_id`, `Appointment_time`, `Appointment_date` FROM `Appointment` WHERE rownum = 1 ; ";
```

Comment: Also follow what alot of others have said about checking, run the code  independently and see if your info is coming from the SQL call, echo it to screen if you have to.. THEN assign it to the session. and echo that..